# How do I click an li inside a ul using Selenium in python?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I would like to click on 'National Data' in this web: https://dataunodc.un.org/GSH_app using the Selenium package in Python.

I tried to do this but it doesn't work. Could anybody help me?

````
driver.get("https://dataunodc.un.org/GSH_app")

html_list = driver.find_element_by_class_name("nav navbar-nav")
all_li = elem.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is avaible inside an iframe.You have to switch to iframe first.Then click on the link `National Data`.

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`()
Induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable`() and following XPATH

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://dataunodc.un.org/GSH_app")
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@src='https://unodc.shinyapps.io/GSH_App/']")))
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//ul[@class="nav navbar-nav"]//a[text()="National Data"]'))).click()
```

OR You can use following CSS selector.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://dataunodc.un.org/GSH_app")
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src='https://unodc.shinyapps.io/GSH_App/']")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'ul.nav.navbar-nav a[data-value="National Data"]'))).click()
```

**Browser snapshot:**
[image]

---

To click on all checkbox try this code.

```
allchekbox=WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@name='YearVar' and not(@checked='checked')]")))
print(len(allchekbox))

for item in allchekbox:
    item.click()
```